# Can I use stop-loss to create buying/selling orders without positions?

Tags: stocks

If the current market price is at 40 and I expect the price may go up to 45, but I don't want to buy it unless it actually exceeds 45. Can I put a buy-stop order at 45, so when the market price hits 45, a bid market order will be sent?

Comment: Your second sentence is correct, sure.  Your third sentence, I don't understand

Comment: What do you mean by "Or this doesn't work the order will be auto executed?"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A conditional orders allow you to attach stipulations that must be true before an order can be submitted.

An example of a very complex conditional order might be:

- Buy 10 call options on MSFT with a specified limit price of 85 cents, but only when its share price <= $46.45 and Volume >25mm and the S&P 500 index was <= 2,000.

Not all brokers offer conditional orders.

Comment: Isn't a buy stop order sufficient for what the OP wants?

Comment: Yep, that'll do the job.